# Cake PHP Form getting data from input and passing it to the url

Tags: php, cakephp

I have my view controller that grabs a code number from the url

users/view/10024 or  users/view/10004 etc

in my user index.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view2'),
    'type' => 'get',
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
    )


));

echo $this->Form->input(
    'Enter Code',
    array('label' => 'Code')
);

$options = array(
    'label' => 'Submit',
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'glass-pill',
    )
);
```

I get this

```
/users/view?Enter+Code=1001
```

I want

```
/users/view/1001
```

So i want to grab the input data and put it in the url

Comment: There is a way to do /users/view/1001 in cakephp but the question is not clear.

Comment: Is this for filtering? If so you should consider using a more stable approach: https://github.com/CakeDC/search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done using PHP.

Instead you need to use the **rewriting engine** of Apache: **MOD_REWRITE** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Create a simple rewrite rule that transforms the URL in the way you want to achieve.
You can see an example on rewriting URL's here: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: If the question means you want the form to _submit_ to `/users/view/1001` - you need to use javascript, or use the Post->Redirect->Get pattern. There's no rewrite in the question (mod rewrite is normal/expected when using CakePHP).